# Tornado/Spider Charts

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

[Tornado Chart](http://www.epixanalytics.com/modelassist/AtRisk/images/15/image350.gif)

[Spider Chart](http://www.treeplan.com/images/sensit-sensitivity-analysis-spider-chart.gif)

I'm building these two types of charts for a [sensitivity analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) mechanism. Although I didn't find out-of-the-box charts from JavaFX, I would appreciate some concrete workarounds using existing APIs.

*JavaFX 2.2*

Comment: The best starting point for custom charts is the CandlestickChart in the Ensemble demo (part of the samples and demos from the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, we don't even need to go into custom charts for this one.

**Tornado Chart:**

A `LineChart` with `NumberAxis` and `CategoryAxis`. All `Series` will be parallel to the X Axis, then they will be really thick via CSS. They will look more like rectangles rather than lines. The 'tornado' effect is given by the input data.

**Spider Chart:**

Nothing special about this one. `LineChart` with precisely calculated input data, so that the series intersect.